# Emulsifying homemade coconut milk?

Tags: food-science, texture, chemistry, coconut, coconut-milk

I've been experimenting with fresh coconuts lately (they are amazing), but one thing I haven't figured out yet is how to make a nice creamy coconut milk. Mainly to make hot chocolate and eat with fruits like an yogurt,

So I put the coconut water and the meat in a (not very good) blender, strained it through a sieve and refrigerated it, this is the result:

[image]

The part at the top is a grainy, watery coconut mush, I was expecting it to be like cream/yogurt

And the part at the bottom I assume it's really just coconut water.

Looking at a carton of store-bought full fat coconut milk it contains chemical emulsifiers and thickeners, so is there no way of achieving a natural creamy coconut milk?

And the store bought one never mentions it was pasteurized, one of my ideas was water bathing the glass.

I also thought abount whisking it but not sure about it yet.

So, what can be done to achieve a homogenous, creamy, eat-by-itself, homemade coconut milk?

In regards to the duplicate question, I want to know how to emulsify it, the store bought ones do not completely separate this way and the top part is creamy unlike mine.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate, I'm asking for techniques to emulsify it